# how to grant user teminal access in VNC

Tags: vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I have server CentOS 5.2 that has GUI, ORACLE 10g R2 installed on it, I want to provide any DBA who will use the system access to the server via VNC, but I don't want to share the GUI, only terminal appear, is that possible, thanks

**EDIT**

lets say I have ORACLE user and the password is ORACLE, when I add the following tags to the VNC I can access the gnome interface.

```
VNCSERVERS="2:oracle"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1024x800"
```

Comment: Why not give him SSH terminal access instead ? BTW this question might be better suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I thought  about it, but if I granted them ssh access via putty, it need some configuration from the user end and that will be too hard due large number of uses.

Comment: what kind of configuration are you thinking of specifically ? I assume the DBA already has a user name + password, since that would be needed on VNC as well.

Comment: they have access to the GUI (gnome), but recently my manager asked me to disable the gnome interface when they are using VNC.